# list to grid view using mootools

Tags: javascript, listview, gridview, mootools, show-hide

I'm working on a marketplace type website built using a CMS which uses Mootools JS and I'd like to give the user the option to change from a List View of items to a Grid View.

My problem is upon loading the screen both List and Grid Views are seen and only one disappears when a button is clicked so this is where I need help. I'd like for the List View to appear on the page loading and the Grid View to appear on the button click

I've done tons of research on this and while there's plenty of JQuery answers there's not much at all for Mootools and the only answers I could find suggested using CSS 'display: none' on one of the list elements and that really doesn't work at all.

You can see a basic idea of my problem in http://jsfiddle.net/5ctJL/5/

Here is my HTML

```
<button id="list">list</button>
<button id="grid">grid</button>

<ul id="ulGrid">
  <li>Grid 1</li>
  <li>Grid 2</li>
  <li>Grid 3</li>
  <li>Grid 4</li>
  <li>Grid 5</li>
</ul>
<ul id="ulList">
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
  <li>List 4</li>
  <li>List 5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#ulGrid {
  color: #8A7575;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 15%;
}

#ulList {
  color: #8A7575;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

JS

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {

  var myList = new Fx.Slide('ulList');
  var myGrid = new Fx.Slide('ulGrid');

  $('list').addEvent('click', function (event) {
    myGrid.hide();
    myList.show();
  });

  $('grid').addEvent('click', function (event) {
    myGrid.show();
    myList.hide();
  });

});
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: this is something you can solve via a simple CSS class. you could even decouple it from the ids / logic and make it more generic like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/5ctJL/6/

Comment: You're a star @DimitarChristoff! Works perfectly. Could you just explain what the last line of the JS is doing so I can fully understand---
this.set('text', grids.match('#ulGrid.hide')[0] ? 'grid' : 'list')

Comment: it checks if the collection of elements matches a hidden grid element, then changes the text on the toggle button accordingly.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff, care to post a answer? I have some upvotes I would like to fire away...

Comment: agreed I'd like to vote for the correct answer @DimitarChristoff

Comment: @DimitarChristoff in ref to "test.set..." question, I thought as much as I found I could change the text but how do I change it to icons. I see Ebay has a list and grid icons that look way better than normal buttons

Comment: define a class and add the class to the button instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so. try to decouple from IDs and thick/rigid logic.

```
var grids = document.getElements('.grid > ul');    
document.getElements('.grid button.toggler').addEvent('click', function(){
    grids.toggleClass('hide');
    this.set('text', grids.match('#ulGrid.hide')[0] ? 'grid' : 'list');
});
```

with a markup of:

```
<div class="grid">
    <button class="toggler">grid</button>    
    <ul id="ulGrid" class="hide">
        <li>Grid 1</li>
        <li>Grid 2</li>
        <li>Grid 3</li>
        <li>Grid 4</li>
        <li>Grid 5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="ulList">
        <li>List 1</li>
        <li>List 2</li>
        <li>List 3</li>
        <li>List 4</li>
        <li>List 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS of:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}

#ulGrid {
    color: #8A7575;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 15%;
}

#ulList {
    color: #8A7575;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

will work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/5ctJL/6/

to answer additional question about icons, here is something via font-awesome.
http://jsfiddle.net/5ctJL/9/

does the same thing but sets class to the correct icon. see http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ for options, I picked two that look like a grid and a list.

```
var grids = document.getElements('.grid > ul');    
document.getElements('.grid button').addEvent('click', function(){
    grids.toggleClass('hide');
    this.set('class', this.hasClass('fa-list') ? 'fa fa-th' : 'fa fa-list');
});
```

nb: keep in mind for the icon version I have done some subtle changes to the markup to avoid also setting the `className` to toggler and have styled the buttons in CSS w/o a namespace - it's proof of concept, not drop in :)

to be honest, I can solve the whole thing in pure CSS (including the click) - if you don't need to support IE8

Comment: I see what's happening but where is the JS getting the fa-th and fa-list icons from? The images have to be included the HTML or CSS surely?

Comment: they are not images. they are glyph web fonts - look at side of fiddle, under resources - it embeds the font awesome css.

Comment: just had a thought, do I need to set a Var linking to the source of the icon images? I've just tried using getElement but as far as I'm aware JS only gets content from ID and Classes in HTML not from folder locations

Comment: I see the resource now, issue solved and many thanks, I'll be implementing this. I don't mean to go on but is there any way of using my own images from my own folder sources rather than having to use an external library like fa? I just want to increase my learning

Comment: yeh just define local classes in your css with background-image or whatever and toggle these. i used font awesome cuz it's awesome. and i can't embed images in jsfiddle.